# rails form submit alternate strings for new and edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using the  `form_for`  helper to produce the edit and new form for a model in one go. The submit presents different strings (e.g. Create Model). However I need these strings to be in German along with a German model name. Is it possible to pass these two Strings to `f.submit`?

Comment: I don't understand this "However I need these strings to be in German along with a German model name". Are you looking for I18N ?

Comment: The internationalisation answers below are good solutions for the first part of the submit Button. But I also want to change the model name in the button to be different. Any idea?

Comment: I have added an example how to translate a model with activerecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localisation for the submit button can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit).
Just create a new file `config/locales/de.yml` and don't forget to change the default language in the `config/application.rb`.

```
de:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Erstelle %{model}"
      update: "Ändere %{model}"

  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Benutzer
```

Comment: BTW, why aren't there default translations included for the rails standard strings?

Comment: Actually there are translations in the rails-i18n gem, you could also add this to your gemfile or copy this file: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml#L127

Answer (score 0):

use rails internationalization create yml files for different languages. In details go to this link
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html